# How to set up relations between features and steps in lettuce?

Tags: python, selenium, autotest, lettuce

I'm using lettuce BDD framework for python. 
In examples all scenarios use methods from only one *.py file - steps.py
How to set up relations between *.feature and its *.py file?

I need these feature files:

```
auth.feature
pay.feature
```

and these py files

```
auth.py
pay.py
```

I need this: scenarios from the `auth.feature` refer to the methods only in `auth.py`
and scenarios from the pay.feature refer only to the methods in `pay.py`

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your steps file:

```
from lettuce import *
from lettuce import steps
```

Then for each step, write this:

```
@step('I make it go')
def i_make_it_go(step):
```